# CSS file not being applied to TPL in bottle

Tags: python, css, templates, static, bottle

my first question here, and im pretty sure its a case of me not knowing completely what im doing

when using a .tpl file (the one in question is 'comments.tpl' stored in /views). it does not retrieve the .css file i would like associated with it.

I've read through a few questions posted on here and on other places but am yet to find something that i can comprehend as a solution.

Here is my code:

```
import bottle
import pymongo
import sys
from bottle import static_file



def connect_db():
    db = pymongo.MongoClient()
    db = db
    return db.reddit.comments

@bottle.route('/static/css/style.css')
def stylesheets(comments):
    return static_file(comments, root='./static/css')

@bottle.route('/')
def home_page():
    db = connect_db()
    result = db.find(limit = 10)
    return bottle.template('comments', username = "YOU", result = result)

@bottle.route('/test_page')
def test_page():
    return "You made it!<br> <a href='/'>Now come back!</a><br>"





bottle.debug(True)
bottle.run(host = 'localhost', port = 8080)
```

the files are set out

```
/---cmt_page.py
 ---/views/comments.tpl               
 ---/static/css/style.css
```

any help would be fantastic, thanks in advance!

-Sam

///////////////**EDIT**//////////////////

Sorted.

Changed :

```
@bottle.route('/static/css/style.css')
def stylesheets(comments):
    return static_file(comments, root='./static/css')
```

To:

```
@bottle.route('/static/css/<style>')
def stylesheets(style):
    return static_file(style, root='./static/css')
```

Always read the bloody documentation kids....

-Sam

Answer (score 0):

try an absolute path in `root='./static/css'`